# Unity dynamic light isn't casting shadows

Tags: unity

I am using the Lightweight Scriptable Render Pipeline 1.1.11-preview and I have two lights in the scene. One is a Sun light and another is an uplight. The Sun light is set to cast dynamic shadows, as are the particle effect clouds and the models. I am expecting the clouds and the cloudship (the floating thing in the middle of the picture) to cast shadows.

The sand is procedurally generated: a flat prefab is loaded at run time and the `y` points are set by Perlinn noise. I recalculate the normals using Unity's method.

Here is the scene:

[image: Rendered scene without clouds]

The properties of the Sun light:

[image: The Sun light properties window]

The prefab for the sand (which I am expecting to have shadows):

[image: Sand prefab properties window]

Here is the lighting properties.

[image: Scene lighting properties screen]

The setting window for the Lightweight Pipeline:

[image: Lightweight scriptable pipeline]

The settings for the mesh that should be casting the shadow:

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lightweight Render Pipeline asset, my distance was set to 50. As my objects are large and set outdoors, this was not far enough to cast shadows. Below, I have set it to 6000 units, which is roughly the render distance of my scene.

[image]